# synchronized keyword and locks on instance methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm studying concurrency at the moment and I was learning about blocking threads.

I know that a thread can come to a blocked state when the corresponding attached task tries to access a method that is locked because another thread acquired the lock.

So from what I've read the task blocks and wait until it can access that method and so goes on with its business (namely, the rest of the run() method).

So why does this code exits like the task could call syn.getI() and access the variable in an "erroneous" state (even if the syn.manipulate() method is locked so I'm assuming the task cannot get to calling getI() ) ? where am I wrong on this?

```
public class SynchronizedClass {
    private int i;
    private boolean flag=true;
    public SynchronizedClass(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }
    public boolean getFlag(){
        return flag;
    }
    public synchronized void manipulate(){
        i=(i*2)+1;  //odd number
        Thread.yield();
        i= i+1; //even number       
    }
    public void close(){
        flag=false;
    }

}
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    //auto-managed runnable
    Thread t;
    SynchronizedClass syn;
    public MyThread(SynchronizedClass syn){
        this.syn=syn;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(syn.getFlag()==true){
            syn.manipulate();
            if (syn.getI()%2!=0){
                syn.close();
                System.out.println("exit");
            }

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchronizedClass syn = new SynchronizedClass(1);
        for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
            new MyThread(syn);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using "task" and "thread" in your description - it's not quite clear whether you mean the same thing by both words or not. I appreciate that English isn't your native language, but it's worth taking a bit more time to clarify your question. Perhaps talk to someone else with the same native language as you, but a better command of English?

Comment: One problem with your example code could be: there is not much "blocking" to happen. Even when you make other calls synchronized too, it is very hard to say what will happen. If your 4 threads come up relatively slow, it could be that they are executed "more in sequence" than in parallel. **synchronized** only comes into play when one thread is "inside" the method; while another is "outside" and trying to get "in". Meaning: you might want to add "sleep" statements inside your synchronized methods to actually enforce "blocking".

Comment: @JonSkeet I my use of "task" and "thread" is due to my not clear understanding of these basic concepts yet, more this than my english (which is not perfect as well..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even if the `syn.manipulate()` method is locked so I'm assuming the task cannot get to calling `getI()`

That's the mistake you're making, I believe.

Just because *one* method is synchronized doesn't implicitly mean that anything else is synchronized. It's not like one thread owning the monitor associated with an object stops other threads from accessing that object - it just stops other threads from acquiring the monitor.

If you make the `getI()` method synchronized, *then* one thread owning the monitor due to `manipulate()` means that other threads calling `getI()` on the same object would have to wait, in order to acquire the monitor.

Comment: yes,that's exactly what I mean, so I expect that another thread can't get to getI() and access the variables in an a wrong state,because the thread is blocked at manipulate and is waiting for the other thread to release the lock, (even if getI() itself is not sync) maybe there's some context switching issue I'm overlooking..

Comment: @Luca: No, it's not context switching - it's your expectation that other threads can't call `getI`. They can, because that method isn't synchronized.

Comment: Yes,but I can't understand : even if getI() is not synced, when a thread arrives at manipulate() it should stop and wait for the lock to be released and carry on to getI() only when the variable is in an acceptable state. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Luca: well I won't be able to enter `manipulate` until it can acquire the lock... But what makes you think that isn't happening? It's not clear what you expect to happen vs what you're seeing. Note that between one thread completing its call to `manipulate` and it then calling `getI`, another thread could call `manipulate`

Comment: That's it! yes,that's what I was talking about when I was saying "context switching"....I was missing that I could go past manipulate() and stop there,then another thread can stop in the middle of manipulate and then I could resume and get a wrong value... right?
Wow, thanks a lot Jon!